# Run-Time Check Failure #2 - Stack around the variable '...' was corrupted

Tags: c++, runtime-error

I'm working on an old C++ project and trying to debug the function below:

```
    inline void WriteByteList( /*[in]*/  PBYTE pbytSrc
                             , /*[in]*/  size_t tSrcSize
                             , /*[out]*/ LPWSTR pszDest
                             , /*[out]*/ size_t tDestSize ) {
        wchar_t szItem[ 12 ], *pszNumber = &szItem[0];
        size_t tSize = sizeof(szItem) / sizeof(szItem[0]);  
        for ( size_t tByte=0; tByte<tSize; tByte++ ) {      
            if ( tByte == 1 ) {
                *pszNumber++ = L' ';
            }
            _ultow_s((unsigned long)pbytSrc[tByte], pszNumber, tSize, 10);
            wcscat_s(pszDest, tDestSize, szItem);
         }
    }
```

I really can't see what's wrong with the code.

Here is the call that creates the problem:

```
    WriteByteList( (PBYTE)pProgramId->Byte, nliPROGRAM_ID_LEN, szMsg, tMsgSize );
```

pProgramId points to a structure, the Byte member is an array of 8 unsigned chars.  This contains the following values:

```
    128, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1
```

nliPROGRAM_ID_LEN is a constant declared as 8.

szMsg is an array declared as:

```
    wchar_t szMsg[500];
```

tMsgSize is the number of elements in szMsg:

```
    tMsgSize = sizeof(szMsg) / sizeof(szMsg[0]);
```

When I iterate through this routine I get:

```
    local variable tSize initialised to 12
    pszNumber initialised to point to szItem
```

Loop iteration 0:
        szItem contains '128', followed by 0 (null)
        pszDest contains '128'

Loop iteration 1:
        szItem contains ' 0'
        pszDest contains '128 0'

Loop iteration 2:
        szItem contains ' 1'
        pszDest contains '128 0 1'

Loop iteration 3:
        szItem contains ' 1'
        pszDest contains '128 0 1 1'

Loop iteration 4:
        szItem contains ' 1'
        pszDest contains '128 0 1 1 1'

Loop iteration 5:
        szItem contains ' 1'
        pszDest contains '128 0 1 1 1 1'

Loop iteration 6:
        szItem contains ' 1'
        pszDest contains '128 0 1 1 1 1 1'

Loop iteration 7:
        szItem contains ' 1'
        pszDest contains '128 0 1 1 1 1 1 1'

When the loop is completed and on leaving the function the message is displayed:

```
    Run-Time Check Failure #2 - Stack around the variable 'szItem' was corrupted.
```

Comment: After you've incremented `pszNumber`, it no longer points to the first of `tSize` elements.

Comment: @molbdnilo, where do you see pzDest being incremented?

Comment: Oops, wrong name. Fixed.

Comment: @molbdnilo, pszNumber is only incremented on iteration 1, that's to insert a space at the beginning of szItem.

Comment: It's possible that `_ultow_s` fills the entire remaining buffer with zeros in order for you to catch buffer overruns. After the increment, that would cause one.

Comment: @molbdnilo, I'm checking in the debugger and I only see the start of szItem being modified, after the '0' null not initialised.

Comment: OK. It was a long shot. (You should still fix that bug, though. There's no point in using the "safe" functions unsafely.)

Comment: @molbdnilo, whats the bug?

Comment: The bug is passing `tSize` to `_ultow_s` when `pszNumber` is `&szItem[1]`. It's only followed by `tSize - 1` elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Re-wrote function:

```
    inline void WriteByteList( /*[in]*/  PBYTE pbytSrc
                             , /*[in]*/  size_t tSrcSize
                             , /*[out]*/ LPWSTR pszDest
                             , /*[out]*/ size_t tDestSize ) {
        wchar_t szItem[ 12 ];
        size_t tSize = sizeof(szItem) / sizeof(szItem[0]);  
        for ( size_t tByte=0; tByte<tSrcSize; tByte++ ) {       
            size_t tOffset = 0;
            szItem[tOffset] = L' ';
            if ( tByte > 0 ) {
                tOffset++;
            }
            _ultow_s((unsigned long)pbytSrc[tByte], &szItem[tOffset], tSize - tOffset, 10);
            wcscat_s(pszDest, tDestSize, szItem);
        }
    }
```

Works now without any error.